# Polymer v1.0 iron-list items layout styling

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using the demo provided for iron-list to fetch json data and create the iron-list items. All is working well.

However when creating a `dom-module` the layout styling for each item is not correct and i suspect `@apply(--layout-horizontal); @apply(--layout-flex); @apply(--layout-vertical);` are not getting picked up.

If i go directly into `iron-flex-layout.html` and copy the css for those layouts the items look ok

I had a look at styling documentation for v.1 but i couldn't see anything obvious in there

Thanks

**Code**

```
<body unresolved>
  <paper-scroll-header-panel class="fit" condenses keep-condensed-header>
  <paper-toolbar class="tall">
  <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
  <div class="flex"></div>
  <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
  <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
  <div class="bottom title">iron-list</div>
</paper-toolbar>
<my-request></my-request>
</paper-scroll-header-panel>

<dom-module id="my-request">
<template>
  <iron-ajax auto id="ajaxPost" url="the-url" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}" on-respone="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
  <iron-list items="{{data.items}}" as="item">
  <style>

    iron-list {
      background-color: var(--paper-grey-200, #eee);

    }

    .item {
      @apply(--layout-horizontal);

      margin: 16px 16px 0 16px;
      padding: 20px;

      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .pad {
      padding: 0 16px;
      @apply(--layout-flex);
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
    }

    .primary {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .secondary {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .dim {
      color: gray;
      position: absolute;
      right: 70px;
      bottom: 10px;
    }
    .more {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10;
      right: 37px;
      color:#D3D3D3;
    }


  </style>
  <template>
    <div>
      <div class="item">
        <iron-image style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);background-color:gray;width:80px; height:80px;" sizing="cover" src="[[item.path]]" preload></iron-image>
        <div class="pad">
          <div class="primary">{{item.the_title}}</div>
          <div class="secondary">{{item.info}}</div>
          <div class="dist secondary dim"><span>{{item.lat}}</span>,<span>{{item.lng}}</span></div>
        </div>
        <iron-icon class="more" icon="star"></iron-icon>
        <iron-icon icon="more-vert"></iron-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-request',
      handleResponse: function() {
        console.log('handleResponse');
      }

    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Tasos. Thanks for wanting to add a solution. Would you move it to a self-answer, please? That way, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick icon to the left - we prefer not to use [solved] title hacks here. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer  yes that's what i wanted to do in the 1st place. I haven't asked that many questions and didn't know about "Answer your own question" button at the bottom of the page. Now i  know.  thanks

Comment: No probs. Also, quick tip: if you want to revert to a prior version, just explore the [version history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31494614/revisions) and choose "Rollback" on the earlier version you want to restore.

Comment: @halfer  that looks nice, didnt know about that either. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had another look at the styling documentation and the examples in there have `<style>...</style>` just underneath the `<dom-module` ... like so

```
<dom-module id="the-id">
<style>
.
.
</style>
```

So placing `<style>..</style>` below `<template>` when using `<dom-module ..`  don't get loaded in.

Comment: That has changed again. `<style>` inside `<dom-module><template>` is the preferred way again.